# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerText')

Tags: javascript, html

below is the Html code find and provide me with the solution.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
           <title> Simple Interest Calculator</title>
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <form class="form1" id="form1">
            <div class="div1">
                <h1> Simple Interest Calculator</h1>
            </div>
                 
                 <div>
                   <span class="frt"><label>Amount</label></span>
                    <pre class="amt" ><input type="text" id="amt"></pre>
                  </div>

                  <table>
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <div>
                          <span class="frt"><label>Interest Rate</label></span>
                           <pre class="amt1" ><input type="range" id="rng" min="0" max="20"></pre>
                         </div>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <div>
                          <h3 id="rangedisplay"></h3>
                        </div>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                  <div>
                   <span class="frt"><label>No. of Years </label></span>
                    <pre class="amt2"><input type="number" class="year"  id="year"></pre>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <input type="button" value="Compute Interest" class="frt" id="button">
                  </div>
                  <span class="sec" id="output"><h2></h2></span>

            </div>
            <div>
            <summary>
                &#169 Everyone Can Get Rich<br>
                This Calculator belongs to <span class="sum">Giri</span>
            </summary>     
        </div>


        </form>
      <script src="web.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

below is the javascript code. Here the problem is with innerText, I could not understand what happened.

please provide me with the solution as soon as possible.

I am new to this domain, please help to fix this issue.

```
let rangeEl=document.querySelector('#rng');
let dis=document.querySelector('#rangedispaly');

rangeEl.addEventListener('input',function() {
   let x=rangeEl.value;
   dis.innerText=x;    
   

});
```

Comment: Typo: `#rangedispaly` should be `#rangedisplay`.

Comment: again I got  same error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerText')
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (web.js:6:17)

Comment: Using the same name [should work fine](https://jsfiddle.net/kvorxb6u/). So just to be clear, the HTML should be `<h3 id="rangedisplay"></h3>` and the JS should be `document.querySelector('#rangedisplay')`.

Answer (score -1):

```js
let rangeEl=document.querySelector('#rng');
let dis=document.querySelector('#rangedisplay');

rangeEl.addEventListener('input',function() {
 let x = rangeEl.value;
  dis.innerHTML = x
   

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
           <title> Simple Interest Calculator</title>
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <form class="form1" id="form1">
            <div class="div1">
                <h1> Simple Interest Calculator</h1>
            </div>
                 
                 <div>
                   <span class="frt"><label>Amount</label></span>
                    <pre class="amt" ><input type="text" id="amt"></pre>
                  </div>

                  <table>
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <div>
                          <span class="frt"><label>Interest Rate</label></span>
                           <pre class="amt1" ><input type="range" id="rng" min="0" max="20" step="1"></pre>
                         </div>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <div>
                          <h3 id="rangedisplay"></h3>
                        </div>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                  <div>
                   <span class="frt"><label>No. of Years </label></span>
                    <pre class="amt2"><input type="number" class="year"  id="year"></pre>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <input type="button" value="Compute Interest" class="frt" id="button">
                  </div>
                  <span class="sec" id="output"><h2></h2></span>

            </div>
            <div>
            <summary>
                &#169 Everyone Can Get Rich<br>
                This Calculator belongs to <span class="sum">Giri</span>
            </summary>     
        </div>


        </form>
      <script src="web.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: It is generally encouraged to explain what you changed and why it makes a difference. Otherwise your answer will turn into a game of "spot the difference" (both for OP and future visitors). That being said, in this case the question is caused by a typographical error and should be closed as such instead of answered. This will very likely not be useful to future visitors, which is what Stack Overflow is all about.

Comment: You said this part in comment section and i complated answer section!

Comment: Yes, but I put this in a comment, _because_, as I just said, it shouldn't be in an answer. It wont help future visitors and only makes it harder to remove questions like these.